# How to create a custom block returning CRLF (carriage return + line feed) as string in blockly

Tags: newline, constants, block, blockly

I am a beginner at blockly.

For string concatenation in blockly I need a custom block (JavaScript) just returning CRLF (carriage return + line feed) but on executing it throws this error

> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I've created the block and code:

```js
    Blockly.Blocks['paragraph_add_crlf'] = {
        init: function() {
            this.appendDummyInput()
                .appendField("CRLF");
            this.setOutput(true, "String");
            this.setColour(160);
            this.setTooltip("CRLF");
            this.setHelpUrl("");
        }
    };

    Blockly.JavaScript['paragraph_add_crlf'] = function(block) {
        var code = "'\r\n'";
        return [code, Blockly.JavaScript.ORDER_NONE];
    };
```

[image: my custom CRLF block]

Console output of the generated JavaScript code:

```js
    content += ('
');
```

Exception on running that code:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at run (blockly.php:287)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (blockly.php:212)
```

**My Question**

What do I have to change to get CRLF as string from a custom block in blockly?

Answer (score 0):

Got it: I have to escape the `\`-backslash characters:

```
    Blockly.JavaScript['paragraph_add_crlf'] = function(block) {
        var code = "'\\r\\n'";
        return [code, Blockly.JavaScript.ORDER_NONE];
    };
```

Working example:

[image: custom block in blockly just returning CRLF]